# Operador ternário com três condições possíveis

Tags: javascript

Para um determinado `status`, eu posso ter 3 diferentes estágios, podendo ser:

- 0 = Parado
- 1 = Enviando
- 2 = Entregue

Então poderia ter:
status = 0 ou
status = 1 ou
status = 2

Para cada estágio, eu preciso definir um ícone.

Se eu tivesse apenas dois estágios, sendo 1 ou 2, o código abaixo seria o suficiente para mim.

```
let status = 1;
const sendStatus = `<i class="${status < 2 ? "icon-1" : "icon-2"}"></i>`;
```

Mas, já que existe também o estágio 0, que é o estágio `default`, como posso definir um ícone para o `status 0`, sem utilizar `if` ?

Comment: Não seria algo como `status < 2 ? (status == 1 ? "icon-1" : "icon-0") : "icon-2"`?

Comment: Talvez poderia ser desta forma, mas isso pode ? Eh uma boa prática ?

Comment: Não vejo qualquer problema de se fazer isso.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode usar [operadores ternários](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) aninhados. Algo assim:

```js
function getClass(status) {
  return status === 0
    ? 'default'
    : status === 1
      ? 'icon-1'
      : 'icon-2';
}

console.log(getClass(0));
console.log(getClass(1));
console.log(getClass(2));
```

<sup>Note que criei uma função apenas para demonstrar os três casos possíveis. Você não precisa, necessariamente, criar uma função para alcançar esses resultados.</sup>

No entanto, muitos consideram utilizar operadores ternários aninhados uma má prática, já que pode prejudicar a legibilidade do código. Você pode então utilizar um objeto para mapear uma determinada chave a um valor. Algo assim:

```js
function getClass(status) {
  const map = {
    0: 'default',
    1: 'icon-1',
    2: 'icon-2'
  };

  return map[status];
}

console.log(getClass(0));
console.log(getClass(1));
console.log(getClass(2));
```

Para garantir que um valor sempre seja retornado da expressão, mesmo que o objeto não tenha a chave que foi acessada, você pode usar o [operador lógico OR (`||`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operadores_Logicos#OR_L%C3%B3gico_()):

```js
object[key] || 'Valor padrão';
```

Por exemplo:

```js
const map = {
  0: 'default',
  1: 'icon-1',
  2: 'icon-2'
};

console.log(map[3] || 'default');
```

Alternativamente ao `||`, se o ambiente suportar, o [operador de coalescência nula (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) pode ser mais adequado, já que também permitiria o mapeamento de valores considerados *falsy* pelo `||`, tais como `''`, `0` etc.

Comment: Com certeza a última opção – uma matriz associativa com tratadores – é a mais 'moderna' e bonita, em Python também seria considerado o mais 'pythônico'.

Answer (score 4):

```
let status = 1;
const sendStatus = `<i class="${status == 0 ? 'icon-0' : status == 1 ? 'icon-1' : 'icon-2'}"></i>`;
```

---

```
let status = 1;
const sendStatus = `<i class="${'icon-' + status}"></i>`;
```

---

```
let icons = ['icon-0', 'icon-1', 'icon-2']
let status = 1;

const sendStatus = `<i class="${icons[status]}"></i>`;
```

Várias formas de resolver isso.

Comment: O nome `icon-1` ou `icon-2` é somente um exemplo, na verdade `icon-?` Terá outro nome, por exemplo, `fa-check`

Comment: Não é boa prática inserir o HTML dentro do JS sendo que já é possível muda-lo pelo próprio HTML. (Isso não levando em consideração o React, aí é outra história)

Comment: Discordo, dependendo da situação, o próprio javascript possui a função `createElement` para criar elementos HTML dinamicamente

Answer (score 2):

Poderia usar um ternário assim:

```
status é diferente
de 0? (true)
   ↓
status ? status < 2 ? 'icon1' : 'icon2' : 'icon0'
         \___________________________/       ↓
                       |                 se status for
            este bloco é caso status    igual a zero (false)
             seja diferente de zero.
               Se for menor que 2,
                    então é 1
```

**Teste:**

```js
let status = 0;
let sendStatus = `<i class="${status ? status < 2 ? 'icon1' : 'icon2' : 'icon0'}"></i>`;
console.log(sendStatus);

status = 1;
sendStatus = `<i class="${status ? status < 2 ? 'icon1' : 'icon2' : 'icon0'}"></i>`;
console.log(sendStatus);

status = 2;
sendStatus = `<i class="${status ? status < 2 ? 'icon1' : 'icon2' : 'icon0'}"></i>`;
console.log(sendStatus);
```

Comment: Uma dúvida, este tipo de código é ou costuma ser usual dentro da programação em geral?

Comment: Wagner, eu já utilizei isso algumas vezes em certas ocasiões. Se é comum de ser utilizado eu não sei dizer com precisão, pois cada programador pode ter um estilo diferente de escrever que acha melhor. Eu vejo por aí muitas coisas usuais e comuns que eu não gosto de usar. Aí vai de cada um.

Comment: Tendo a acreditar que isso seja comum, pq vejo como forma mais eficiente e simples de alcançar o resultado esperado.